# Having issue with repeatinterval every 30 minutes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I am trying to repeat a local notification every 30 minutes but my code does not work fine ... I would be grateful if you help me and find the solution , here is my code :

```
UILocalNotification *reminderNote = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 30];
reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
reminderNote.alertBody = @"some text";
reminderNote.alertAction = @"View";
reminderNote.soundName = @"sound.aif";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`firedate` sets the time that the notification fires the first time, and `repeatInterval` is the interval between between repetitions of the notification. So the code in the question schedules a notification to fire 30 minutes (60 * 30 seconds) from now, and then repeat every hour.

Unfortunately, you can only schedule notifications to repeat at exact intervals defined by NSCalendar [constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSWeekCalendarUnit): e.g., every minute, every hour, every day, every month, but not at multiples of those intervals.

Luckily, to get a notification every 30 minutes, you can just schedule two notifications: one right now, one 30 minutes from now, and have both repeat every hour. Like so:

```
UILocalNotification *reminderNote = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 30];
reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;
reminderNote.alertBody = @"some text";
reminderNote.alertAction = @"View";
reminderNote.soundName = @"sound.aif";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];

reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];
```

Comment: thank you and about every 1 hour or 2 or 3 Should I something like this ? for example every 1 hour :`reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60];
reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSHourCalendarUnit;` and second fire date `reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60];`

Comment: For every 1 hour, you only need to schedule one notification. Just take the code in my answer and get rid of the last two rows. If necessary, change the `fireDate` so that it corresponds to the first time when you want the notification to fire.

Comment: what about every 2 hours or 3 ? is it right ? :     `reminderNote.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60 * 60 * 2]; 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:reminderNote];`

Comment: No. If you wanted to do every 2 (or 3) hours you would have to schedule 12 (or 8) daily notifications, with their initial fireDates spaced 2 (or 3) hours apart.

Remember, you can only schedule a notification that repeats every one hour or every day (or every minute, week, etc., but those aren't useful to you). To make something that **effectively** repeats for a multiple of one of these units, you make multiple notifications that repeat at an interval that is **longer** than the actual interval you want.

Comment: Thank you @yuji. It helped really :)